# Is it possible to use shared object libraries of ubuntu in FreeBSD?

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, makefile, freebsd

I have developed a project in language `C` on `ubuntu 12.04` and I have some shared-object libraries (.so files). Now I want to use that libraries on `freeBSD 8.3` OS. Is this possible? If not how can I do that? Is that necessary to compile my source files on freeBSD?

Comment: No it's not possible.  Yes you must compile your source files on FreeBSD.

Comment: You should publish your project as free software (e.g. on `github`) and recompile it on FreeBSD.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't want to publicize my codes.

Comment: Why? Are you naive to believe other people would your *binary* code (for Linux) on FreeBSD?

Comment: @MadScientist: Had you experimented this issue before?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I have developed a special project for my corporation on ubuntu and it's legal to publicize my binaries or source code on github. I just want to know is there any clean way to export my binaries for using on freeBSD or not.

Comment: If it is corporate code, you should compile it for FreeBSD (and you should request from your boss the needed computer & work-time resources)

Comment: If you want to publish freebsd binaries in addition to Linux binaries, you can just run freebsd (it's trivial to spin up in a virtual machine for example) and compile it there, then publish the binaries.  However, you say you have permission to publish the source so that's by far the best way to go.

Comment: @sajad If you want to compile your code for FreeBSD, consider updating your FreeBSD to version 10.1 first. Version 8.3 is not supported anymore and support (security bug fixes) for 8.4 will [probably end](http://www.freebsd.org/security/security.html#sup) in June 2015. For your information, FreeBSD also works on 64-bit machines. The version for 64-bit Intel architectures is called "amd64" for historical reasons.

Comment: @Roland Smith: Thank you, I will express that; but you know, there is a server that has been configured before and I have to just add my libraries to that. Upgrading of OS is not planned now untill essential update is performed on our product for later installations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andras is talking about running Linux *binaries*.  You are talking about using Linux *shared libraries* (presumably with programs that are compiled on FreeBSD).  That's an entirely different thing.

It's potentially possible to run some fairly limited set of Linux binaries on FreeBSD because the FreeBSD kernel provides a module which exports a Linux-compatible shim layer.  However to make this work you must have all-Linux user-space: you must have Linux-built shared libraries, Linux-built binaries, etc.  See https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu.html

It cannot work to have a binary compiled on FreeBSD use a shared library compiled on Linux.  They have different C runtimes, different kernel system calls, etc.  It won't work, just like using Linux shared libraries on Mac OSX, Solaris on Intel, or any other operating system won't work.

Comment: oh!  that never occurred to me, I thought he would use the linux binary to run the .so... if FreeBSD supports ELF, a carefully crafted .so with no external dependencies might work (perhaps with linux ELF .o's linked into an .so under FreeBSD.)  But this is speculation, beyond my hands-on experience.  But if the sources are available, it would be easier to port them.

Comment: I thank you both for your useful comments. I read the article. I found out that, generally it is not possible to do that. Also my binaries are 64 bit and it is absolutely not supported to use them on freeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

freebsd used to be able to run linux binaries, and included a set of linux .so's in the package.  So it was possible at one point

Comment: Had you experimented this issue before?

Comment: no, but I did use one of my compiled linux programs on freebsd.  It loaded the linux system .so's that came with freebsd